# Set live wallpaper as background for activity

Tags: android

I know that with WallpaperManager we can use getFastDrawable()/getDrawable() to get a static wallpaper thus set it as the background of my activity. But what about live wallpaper, I've read the documentations of WallpaperManager and done some googling only to find that setting the style in xml is the only way. So is there a way so I can get and set the live wallpaper programmatically? Thanks.